# Do single cores with higher clock perform faster than multiple cores with lower clock speeds?

Tags: cpu, threads, cpu-cores

First of all, let me specify my use case.

I use Xampp on locahost to develop websites on my desktop, usually Drupal or Wordpress sites.

My goal is to have this work as fast as possible, as in navigating between pages when working on the website offline. Xampp is faster than doing it online, but still I would like it to be as fast as possible.

I now use an i5-8400 with 16 Gigs of RAM, no graphics cards, EvoPro 970 NVME and all SSD's.

I'm debating getting the i9-9900k with 8 cores/16 threads or Ryzen 3900x with 12 cores/24 threads.

Now the Intel has higher clock speed and IPS than the ryzen, but the ryzen has more cores/threads.

I don't play any video games, all productivity. I like things snappy, makes workflow much faster.

So basically, what system will have the more "torque"?

Comment: The answers to this question will vary based on so many other factors that it cannot be answered conclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Clock speed and thread count are not usable to compare performance in the same way, unless there is an apples to apples comparison (same brand, architecture, and generation). Since you are comparing an Intel CPU to a Ryzen CPU, there will not be such an apples to apples comparison. It's best to look at benchmarks for the specific tasks that need to be undertaken.